# Google Firebase Authentication: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, google-plus-signin

I am using `Ionic2` with `Cordova` to **authenticate** a user in `Firebase`.

I can build the app and run it on `iOS Simulator` (`Xcode`). However, as soon as I try log in a user with the following code using `ionic-native ("ionic-native": "2.2.11",) GooglePlus`:

```
  loginGoogleCordova(): void {
    GooglePlus.login(['public_profile', 'email']).then(googleData => {
      let provider = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleData.authResponse.accessToken);
      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(provider).then((data) => {
        this.signIn(data);
      });
    }, error => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
      console.error('loginGoogle: ' + error);
      this.doAlert('loginGoogle: ' + error.message);
    });
  }
```

I get the following error:

> 2017-03-06 07:55:06.433 theWhoZoo[10489:868996] *** WebKit discarded
>   an uncaught exception in the
>   webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:
>   delegate:  -[__NSArrayM
>   objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x6100002471a0

**More Info:**

I can successfully authenticate a user in a browser with `AngularFire2`.

```
  loginGoogleBrowser() {
    this.auth.login({ provider: AuthProviders.Google, method: AuthMethods.Popup }).then((data: FirebaseAuthState) => {
      this.signIn(data);
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
      console.error('loginGoogle', error);
      this.doAlert('loginGoogle: ' + error.message);
    });
  }
```

Any help appreciated.